# How to clean a string and keep only people's name inside the column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-cleaning

I am working with a CSV file which shows the presidencial meetings in 2018. The CSV says what the president has done and who he has met on that day. Each row is an appointment on his schedule.

I have a column named "oque" (or "Reunião Ministerial" in the original dataset) and its values are strings. But I want to keep only the people's name (first name, middle name and last name).

So the first row with people's name has the following content:

```
Eliseu Padilha, ministro-chefe da Casa Civil; Henrique Meirelles, ministro de Estado da Fazenda; Ronaldo Nogueira, ministro de Estado do Trabalho; Antônio Neto, presidente das Centrais Sindicais Brasileiras; José Calixto Ramos, presidente Nacional da NCST; Ricardo Patah, presidente Nacional UGT; Deputado Federal Paulo Pereira da Silva, Presidente Nacional da Central Força Sindical e Presidente Nacional do Partido Solidariedade
```

It should show only this: Eliseu Padilha, Henrique Meirelles, Ronaldo Nogueira, Antônio Neto, José Calixto Ramos, Ricardo Patah, Paulo Pereira da Silva.

The dataset is on link below: https://gist.github.com/gabrielacaesar/af8835a0a1c01d16f48f0a7336a8d3f0

My pandas analysis is on the link below:
https://github.com/gabrielacaesar/studyingPython/blob/master/pandas-analysis/jupyter-notebook-president-schedule-pandas-analysis.ipynb

Comment: How would you do this by hand? Do all of the rows have the person's name and title separated by a comma?

Comment: I'm not sure there will be many good solutions to this, at first glance, it looks like the text in those columns is extremely unstructured. A suggestion: I would not `lower` everything. CapitalCase might be a good signal for a name, you could filter for capital-cased words and then maybe do a second pass to filter for common proper nouns, like titles or names of organizations or whatever.

Comment: A suggestion, instead of splitting up the date in the first column use `agenda2018['quando'] = pd.to_datetime(angeda2018['quando'])` making it a date-time column. Much more useful. So, if you ever *do* need the month, for example, you can do `agenda2018['quando'].dt.month` or `agenda2018['quando'].dt.hour`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it, thought its not very straightforward. The idea is to first split the string on semi-colon, and then apply str.extract on each string to extract only the string before comma.

```
df['Name'].str.split(';', expand = True)\
.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.str.extract('([A-Za-z ]+),', expand = False)), axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
## create a new column by splitting the name string on ';'
df['Name'] = df['Reunião Ministerial'].map(lambda x: x.split(';'))

## extract names by splitting on ','
df['Name'] = df['Name'].map(lambda x: ', '.join([y.split(',')[0] for y in x])
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired result you could use list comprehension and extract the first element after splitting by `;` and `,`.

Use re library to remove titles.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

s = 'Eliseu Padilha, ministro-chefe da Casa Civil; Henrique Meirelles, \
ministro de Estado da Fazenda; Ronaldo Nogueira, ministro de Estado do\
Trabalho; Antônio Neto, presidente das Centrais Sindicais Brasileiras; José \
Calixto Ramos, presidente Nacional da NCST; Ricardo Patah, presidente Nacional\
UGT; Deputado Federal Paulo Pereira da Silva, Presidente Nacional da Central Força\
Sindical e Presidente Nacional do Partido Solidariedade'

# Recreate dataframe with string (s) two times
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(oque=[s,s]))

titles = ['Deputado Federal ','General ']

df['oque'] = (df['oque'].apply(lambda x: 
              [re.sub('|'.join(titles),'',i.split(', ')[0]) for i in x.split('; ')]))

# Print first row
print(df['oque'][0])
```

Returns:

```
['Eliseu Padilha',
 'Henrique Meirelles',
 'Ronaldo Nogueira',
 'Antônio Neto',
 'José Calixto Ramos',
 'Ricardo Patah',
 'Paulo Pereira da Silva']
```